# How to get active account Id in android multi user

Tags: android

Is there any chance to get  switched(active) account ID in android(L) multi user.
Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID) this one returning first owner android ID as well as user android ID. if user is in active account. I want only active accountid/android

Comment: Use AccountManager class .http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

Answer (score 3):

**[AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)**

> This class provides access to all registered user accounts in device.
>   AccountManager generates the auth tokens for different applications
>   and caches it. It is also responsible for periodic check for the
>   validity of auth tokens.

Please go through below Link. Hope this helps you .

[Get all registered email accounts in Android](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-all-registered-email-accounts-in-android)

Comment: getaccounts() returns all accounts. I want only active account which is in front. which user that is using right now. not all accounts.