# Android multi-user: get current user info

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, android-account, android-multiple-users

Strangely there isn't a question on SO regarding this topic. At least I couldn't find one.

Like Windows & Linux, Android too allows us to have multiple ***user*** accounts on the same device/computer:

[image: android multi users]

Each user is the FIRST (or primary) Google account with which the device/user partition was activated. Hence, one way to get the name/email associated with this user is through *Google Sign-In*:

[image: google sign in pick account dialog]

> My question is, is there a way to get at least the *name* (if not the
>   email) of the device user? Without using Google Sign-In, which
>   requires both the Play Services library ***and*** the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission?

There should be some Android API or `Provider` that tells us the name of the current device user. I've already looked at the following documents:

[Supporting Multiple Users](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user)

[Manage multiple users](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/multiple-users)

[`AccountManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html)

.... and I couldn't find anything there.

Does anyone know of a way to get the name/email of the primary Google account on the current user/partition? WITHOUT Google Sign-In, which requires Play Services? Is there some Java/Android API that gives us the account details for the current user?

**Related**:

**1**. [How to get active account Id in android multi user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31555564/3287204)

**2**. [How `Gmail` does it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38524174/3287204)

**3**. [Getting it without the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51374519/3287204)

**4**. [Getting Android owner's email address nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6502017/3287204)

Comment: Please try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112965/how-to-get-the-android-devices-primary-e-mail-address

Comment: Android users and accounts (e.g. google accounts) are completely irrelevant. Refer to https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/multi-user#general_defs for definitions. Searching about users will not help you reach your purpose.